# Value of variable not changes after increment

Tags: javascript

I have variable to represent position I have `incrementOrRotate` to increment the position if it's value plus one not exceeding the limit say 3 if it exceed then I need make it's value to zero

But the problem that the value never changes , this my code

```
    let pos = 1;

    console.log(incrementOrRotate(pos)); // print 0 it should be 1
    console.log(incrementOrRotate(pos)); // print 0 it should be 2
    console.log(incrementOrRotate(pos)); // print 0 it should be 3
    console.log(incrementOrRotate(pos)); // print 0 it should be 0
    console.log(incrementOrRotate(pos)); // print 0 it should be 1

    function incrementOrRotate(post) {
        pos = pos+1 > 3 ? 0 : pos++;
        return pos;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two issues:

1. JavaScript is a purely pass-by-value language. When you do `incrementOrRotate(pos)`, the **value** of `pos`, not the `pos` variable itself, is passed into the function. Changing the parameter (it's `post` in your question, but you seem to intend it to be `pos` like the variable) doesn't have any effect on the value in `pos` outside the function (unless the function closes over the variable, as it does in yours because of the `post`/`pos` typo).

Instead, assign the result of calling the function to `pos`:

```
    console.log(pos = incrementOrRotate(pos));
    // ---------^^^^^^
```

2. Your code has a typo, you have `post` as the parameter name instead of `pos`. In your code as shown, the `pos` within the function is the `pos` variable the function closes over. But I don't think that was what you meant.

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead. It does the job. Give this a try....

```js
let pos = 0;

console.log(incrementOrRotate()); // print  1
console.log(incrementOrRotate()); // print  2
console.log(incrementOrRotate()); // print  3
console.log(incrementOrRotate()); // print  0
console.log(incrementOrRotate()); // print  1

function incrementOrRotate() {
    pos = pos+1 > 3 ? 0 : pos+1;
    return pos;
}
```